# C++: How to initialize a static vector of a custom member of a class template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, static

This is (a small part of) my struct:

`
struct BASE
{

```
struct s
{

    //...

};


template<typename T>
struct DerivedTemplate : public s
{

    struct SW
    {
        short   ndx = 0;
        double  val = 0;
        bool    glch = false;

        SW(short ndx, double val, bool glch){this->ndx = ndx;this->val = val;this->glch = glch;}
    };

    static vector<SW> SW__BIGGR;

};
```

};`

Then I seek to initialize the vector "SW__BIGGR" in the following way:

```
template <typename T>
vector<BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW> BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW__BIGGR = BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW(0, 0, false);
```

And I get this compiler error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
 vector<BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW> BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW__BIGGR = BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW(0, 0, false);
                                         ^
[...] note:   expected a type, got ‘BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW’
```

When I do the same operation with a vector of simple type such as "int", everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

EDIT:

After adding "typename" before "BASE:: ..." as I was kindly told to do in a comment, I get this error:

error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
vector<typename BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW> typename BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW__BIGGR = typename BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW(0, 0, false);
^

Obviously, the vector cannot be initialized like that (as I am doing without problem with an "int" or "double" vector), but how can it?

EDIT 2:

After deleting "typename" before " ... SW__BIGGR" as kindly suggested, I now get this error for which I could not find an answer googling ("sgnl__01" is a struct based on the struct template "DerivedTemplate"):

"error: conversion from ‘BASE::DerivedTemplateBASE::sgnl__01::SW’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vectorBASE::DerivedTemplate<BASE::sgnl__01::SW, std::allocatorBASE::DerivedTemplate<BASE::sgnl__01::SW> >’ requested vector<typename BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW> BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW__BIGGR = typename BASE::DerivedTemplate::SW(0, 0, false);" Lost again :-(

Comment: In short, the `SW` in `BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW` is a *dependent name*, so you need `typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW`.

Comment: Thank you! I have added "typename" before all three "BASE:: ...", and now I get this error instead: "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token   vector<typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW> typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW__BIGGR = typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW(0, 0, false);"

Comment: Unlike `BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW`, `BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW__BIGGR` is *not* a dependent name, and doesn't need the `typename` prefix.

Comment: Thanks very much again! One step forward, but my cluelessness does not stop there because now I get this error: "error: conversion from ‘BASE::DerivedTemplate<BASE::sgnl__01>::SW’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<BASE::DerivedTemplate<BASE::sgnl__01>::SW, std::allocator<BASE::DerivedTemplate<BASE::sgnl__01>::SW> >’ requested
 vector<typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW> BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW__BIGGR = typename BASE::DerivedTemplate<T>::SW(0, 0, false);" Lost again :-(

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid: seems the {} where missing around the right side of the assignment.